# Is this a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am learning SDE, and here is some basic things I have trouble with,

Let $B(t)$ be a Brownian motion, and $F \in \mathcal L^2$ is any stochastic process and I know $\int_0^tF(s)dB(t)$ is Ito process so$\int_0^tF(s)dB(t)$ is a martingale, but is it a Brownian motion?

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but does it seem even remotely 
possible that this stochastic integral is a Brownian motion
for every $F\in{\cal L}^2$? Including the case when $F$ is identically zero?
Your book or lecture notes must surely be giving you better 
guidance that this.

Comment: yes, thanks. and can we calculate $\int_0^t B(s)ds$? and its expectation?

Comment: @DylanZhu What do you mean by "calculate"? In order to find the expectation, apply Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Compute variance of increment from time $t$ to time $s$ using Ito's isometry
\begin{align}
E[(\int_t^s F(u)dB(u))^2] = E(\int_t^s(F(u))^2du) = \int_t^sE(F(u))^2du
\end{align}

In general, it's not compatible with the variance of Brownian increment, which is $s-t$.